# Binomial Distribution Proof when p > 1/2

Tags: probability

I have the following equality to prove.

Given $X \sim Bin(n, p)$ and $Y \sim Bin(n, 1 - p)$ prove that $P(X \leq k) = P(Y \geq n - k)$. I have been trying to come up with a solution but cannot find one. I am looking for suggestions and not a complete answer as this is a homework question.

What I did until now is the following:

$P(X \leq k) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i} = 1 - \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i} = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - k - 1} \binom{n}{j + k + 1} p^{j + k + 1} (1 - p)^{n - j - k - 1}$

Here , $j = i - k - 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Alicia flips a biased coin $n$ times. The coin has probability $p$ of landing heads. Let $X$ be the number of heads she gets, and $Y$ the number of tails.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} = \sum_{j=n-k}^{n}\binom{n}{n-j}(1-1+p)^{n-j}(1-p)^j$$
where $j=n-i$, or $i=n-j$.